# Schedule + OutputPanel + SelectOneRadio issue

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm facing a strange problem here. In my page i have two **outputPanel**. Inside the first, there is a **schedule** exhibiting my events queried from the database. Inside the other one, there is a **datatable** exhibiting the same events just as another means of visualization. Furthermore, there is a **selectOneRadio** that alternates between the two outputPanels. The problem is: When the page loads, the default outputPanel (the one containing the schedule) (SCREEN 1) is loaded perfectly. But when i alternate the selectOneRadio to the outputPanel containing the datatable and then turn back (SCREEN 2), the outputPanel doesn't load. And the console of the browser shows the following message when i click anywhere on the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined primefaces.js.xhtml:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined primefaces.js.xhtml:16
```

Here is the xhtml page:

```
<!-- Painel de seleção do tipo de exibição -->
            <p:panelGrid columns="2"
                         styleClass="gridNoLine clearBelow">
                <p:selectOneRadio value="#{eventoBean.tipoExibicaoSelecionada}">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{eventoBean.onTipoExibicaoAlterada}"
                            update=":frmEventos:opCalendario :frmEventos:opTabela"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Exibir calendário"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Exibir tabela"/>
                </p:selectOneRadio>
            </p:panelGrid>

            <!-- Painel do Calendário -->
            <p:outputPanel id="opCalendario">
                <p:schedule id="sEventos"
                            value="#{eventoBean.customScheduleModel}"
                            widgetVar="schEventos"
                            locale="pt"
                            rendered="#{eventoBean.tipoExibicaoSelecionada == 1}">
                    <p:ajax event="eventSelect" 
                            listener="#{eventoBean.onEventSelect}" 
                            update=":frmDetalhesEvento"
                            immediate="true" 
                            oncomplete="dlgDetalhesEvento.show();"/>
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
                            listener="#{eventoBean.onDataSelecionada}"
                            update="@form :frmNovoEditarEvento"
                            oncomplete="dlgNovoEditarEvento.show();"/>
                </p:schedule>
            </p:outputPanel >

            <!-- Painel do DataTable -->
            <p:outputPanel id="opTabela">
                <p:dataTable
                    value="#{eventoBean.eventos}"
                    paginator="true" rows="5" 
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10"
                    paginatorPosition="bottom"
                    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    var="evento"
                    rendered="#{eventoBean.tipoExibicaoSelecionada == 2}"
                    emptyMessage="Não há eventos para exibição">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Eventos
                    </f:facet>
                    <!-- Colunas de edição e exclusão -->
                    <p:column styleClass="commandColumn">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Editar"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:commandButton image="ui-icon-pencil" 
                                         title="Editar"
                                         update=":frmNovoEditarEvento:pNovoEditarEvento"
                                         oncomplete="dlgNovoEditarEvento.show();">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{evento}" 
                                                         target="#{eventoBean.eventoSelecionado}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column styleClass="commandColumn">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel 
                                value="Excluir"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:commandButton id="cbViewExcluir" 
                                         oncomplete="dlgExcluir.show();" 
                                         icon="ui-icon-close" 
                                         title="Excluir">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{evento}"
                                                         target="#{eventoBean.eventoSelecionado}" />
                        </p:commandButton> 
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="#{evento.nmeEvento}" 
                              styleClass="wrap tableTitleWidth">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Nome
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="1" 
                                     styleClass="gridNoLine">
                            <h:outputLabel id="olViewNomeEvento" 
                                           value="#{evento.nmeEvento}" 
                                           styleClass="t2"/>
                            <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="gridNoLine wrap">
                                <h:outputLabel value="Início: " styleClass="t3"/>&nbsp;
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{evento.dtaInicioEvento}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <h:outputLabel value="Término: " styleClass="t3"/>&nbsp;
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{evento.dtaTerminoEvento}"/>&nbsp;
                            </p:panelGrid>
                            <p:separator title="Descrição do evento"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{evento.dscEvento}" 
                                           styleClass="wrap"/>
                            <p:panelGrid columns="4" 
                                         styleClass="gridNoLine">
                                <p:commandButton value="Atividades"
                                                 styleClass="commandButton"
                                                 title="Gerenciar as atividades do evento."
                                                 action="atividades"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="Recursos"
                                                 styleClass="commandButton"
                                                 title="Alocar recursos para o evento."/>
                                <p:commandButton value="Serviços"
                                                 styleClass="commandButton"
                                                 title="Alocar serviços para o evento."/>
                                <p:commandButton value="Participantes"
                                                 styleClass="commandButton"
                                                 title="Gerenciar participantes do evento."/>
                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:outputPanel>
```

And here is my bean:

```
...

private int tipoExibicaoSelecionada = 1;

...

public void onTipoExibicaoAlterada() {
    if (tipoExibicaoSelecionada == 1) { // Exibir como calendario

        // Realizando a lógica de painéis
        exibirComoCalendario = true;
        exibirComoTabela = !exibirComoCalendario;

    } else { // Exibir como DataTable

        // Realizando a lógica de painéis
        exibirComoCalendario = false;
        exibirComoTabela = !exibirComoCalendario;

        if (eventos == null) {
            try {
                // Consultar os eventos para exibir no DataTable
                eventos = eventoService.consultarTodos();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onEventSelect(ScheduleEntrySelectEvent entrySelectEvent) {

    try {
        // Transformando o evento para Pojo
        eventoSelecionado = ScheduleEventConverter.convertToEventoPojo(eventoService, entrySelectEvent.getScheduleEvent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public void onDataInicioAlterada(DateSelectEvent e) {
}

public void onDataTerminoAlterada(DateSelectEvent e) {
}

public void onDataSelecionada(DateSelectEvent e) {
    // Gerando um novo evento para ser preenchido
    eventoSelecionado = new TbEvento();

}

public void loadModel() {

    try {

        // Carregando o custom schedule model
        customScheduleModel = new CustomScheduleModel();

        // Carregando a lista de publicos
        publicos = publicoService.consultarTodos();

        // Carregando os tipos de eventos
        tiposEventos = tipoEventoService.consultarTodos();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I'm using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

SCREEN 1:

[image]

SCREEN 2:

[image]

Comment: try it with unmodified primefaces jar... also try updating without form prefix `update="opCalendario opTabela"`

Comment: @Daniel I'm already using an unmodified version of primefaces (3.4.2), and i did as you say (update="opCalendario ...") but it didn't work. More hints?

Comment: try to replace `<p:selectOneRadio & p:ajax` with `<h:selectOneRadio & f:ajax` (also i'm not a maven user , do double check that you really using only 3.4.2 http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17954 )

Comment: @Daniel I've done like you say and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `<p:selectOneRadio` & `p:ajax` with `<h:selectOneRadio` & `f:ajax`

I'm not a maven user , do double check that you really using only 3.4.2 and take a look at this thread... [[PF 3.1 Snapshot] Dialog + OverlayPanel + SelectOneMenu JS E](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17954)